# Como puedo hacer un procedimiento almacenado para insertar dos tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Buenas noches tengo dos tablas que se llaman entidadesBancarias y la otra es sucursales y se relacionan por medio del campo codigoEntBancarias, deseo saber como hacer un procedimiento almacenado que al insertar la clave primaria de la tabla entidadesBancarias este mismo numero me lo inserte como foranea en la tabla sucursales, con los mismos datos tengo el siguiente codigo.
RELACION TABLAS:

```
create table entidadesBancarias(
codigoEntBancarias int primary key,
domicilioCentral varchar (50)
)

create table sucursales(
codigoSucursal int primary key,
domicilioSucursal varchar(50),
numeroEmpleados int,
codigoEntBancarias int
)
```

PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

```
alter procedure sp_insertarDatosSucursales
-----------tabla entidades bancarias---------------------------------

@domicilioCentral varchar(50),
@codigoEntBancarias int  output,
---------tabla sucursal-----------------------------
@codigoSucursal int ,
@domicilioSucursal varchar(50),
@numeroEmpleados int




as
begin
insert into entidadesBancarias(domicilioCentral,codigoEntBancarias)values (@domicilioCentral,@codigoEntBancarias)

insert into sucursales(codigoSucursal,domicilioSucursal,numeroEmpleados)values(@codigoSucursal,@domicilioSucursal,@numeroEmpleados)

end
```

Comment: Podrias ponerlo en forma de respuesta porfavor? Asi queda mas claro que se trata de una respuesta y el código queda mas prolijo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera

```
create procedure sp_insertarDatosEntBancariasSucursales(
@domicilioCentral varchar(50),
@codigoEntBancarias int,
@codigoSucursal int ,
@domicilioSucursal varchar(50),
@numeroEmpleados int)

as
begin
insert into entidadesBancarias(domicilioCentral,codigoEntBancarias)values (@domicilioCentral,@codigoEntBancarias)

insert into sucursales(codigoSucursal,domicilioSucursal,numeroEmpleados,codigoEntBancarias)values(@codigoSucursal,@domicilioSucursal,@numeroEmpleados,@codigoEntBancarias)

end
```